# React - Retrieving and printing data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, loops, infinite

I'm a beginner in React and I'm trying to understand how things work.. I try to experiment with a Firebase database and I don't understand the behaviour.

Here's the CodeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-firebase-d3elg

First, when you open the page, you'll see in console :

```
First ?undefined 
First ?undefined 
Second ?undefined 
Second ?undefined
```

The undefined thing is okay, I'll come back to this later, but why is it printed twice ?

Then, if you uncomment the line 24, **which I highly don't recommend :D**, you start an infinite loop, very aggressive. I was expecting that it fire only 'once' like it's written on line 10 but it doesn't, obviously..

Can someone help me to understand ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put any code that you want run once inside a useEffect with an empty array dependency to make it run once only.

but in the example below in which i edited your sandbox, i put in `dbRef` as a dependency so whenever that value changes, the function is called again.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-firebase-xir7p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: OOoh that's interesting ! I might try that in my app. I'm struggeling with memory leak and I'm affraid it's related ! See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420872/react-cant-find-the-leak-infinite-state-declaration-suspected